# What to do if user refuses to use cookie?

Tags: authentication, cookies

I want to add popup that asks user if website can use cookies but I use cookie for authentication and if user refuses to cookie what to do?
And what message should be in popup?

I expect to somehow use cookie for user authentication.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.